# Labels from nodes to daemonset/kube-prometheus-exporter-node

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

prometheus-operator includes DaemonSet to deploy node-exporter to every node in cluster. It works, but we lack some useful label information, for example:

```
# kubectl get nodes --all-namespaces --show-labels=true
NAME                            STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION    LABELS
ip-1   Ready     master    2d        v1.10.12   ...,kubernetes.io/role=master,...
=
ip-2   Ready     node      2d        v1.10.12   ...,kubernetes.io/role=node,...
```

So we have useful info in labels - ip-1 is master, ip-2 is worker etc.

BUT this information is lost on node-exporter targets, because node labels are not propagated to daemonset node-exporter pods.

So in prometheus, I can't group nodes by their type, for example.

Maybe there's a way how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to use [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#)

This is an example: https://www.robustperception.io/automatically-monitoring-ec2-instances

P.S. As for roles specific, you can find usefull this post as well: [How to have labels for machine roles](https://www.robustperception.io/how-to-have-labels-for-machine-roles)

Update:
To get other node details, not available from metadata, sidecar or init container can be used, for example: [init container for node properties example](https://gist.github.com/gmaslowski/117f3535173d733e007d0c6c83564888).

Also, it is open issue to make node labels available for pod: [40610](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40610)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I understand the principle. But in prometheus-operator node-exporters are running on daemonset's pods. Pod itself (if I'm not mistaken) can't access node-specific information (node labels, for example). 

So on pod level we have no any helpful information. I tried to search some info and it's looks like this functionality cannot be provided by kube or prometheus-operator. People use sidecar containers etc. :(

Comment: Actually, you're right. Found some relevant posts, updating the answer.

Comment: Evgeny, thank you for collecting all the information in one place. For now it can be considered as an answer, I think :)

Answer (score 10):

The reason that node-exporter metrics in prometheus lack node information but have pod information is because prometheus-operator provides a [ServiceMonitor for node-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/0c0643f984fd102075323d5388ed852a12fb453c/manifests/nodeExporter-serviceMonitor.yaml), which sets up a scrape configuration with a `kubernetes_sd_config.role` of [endpoints](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#endpointslice), this only gets the `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint` and `__meta_kubernetes_pod` metalabels.

We want to use a scrape configuration with a `kubernetes_sd_config.role` of [node](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#node). To do this the node-exporter scrape endpoint must be reachable on the node address, the provided daemonset for node-exporter [already exposes port 9100 on the node](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/0c0643f984fd102075323d5388ed852a12fb453c/manifests/nodeExporter-daemonset.yaml#L78).

The next step is to give prometheus-operator an [additional scrape config](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md#creating-an-additional-configuration) to discover node-exporter via the nodes rather than the service and copy over any of the node labels we might want:

```yaml
- job_name: node-exporter
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+):.*
    replacement: $1:9100
    target_label: __address__
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    target_label: name
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_label_beta_kubernetes_io_arch]
    target_label: arch
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_label_beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type]
    target_label: instance_type
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_label_kubernetes_io_os]
    target_label: os
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_label_topology_kubernetes_io_region]
    target_label: region
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_label_topology_kubernetes_io_zone]
    target_label: zone
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_label_dedicated] # or any other custom label
    target_label: dedicated
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node
```

After this you can delete node-exporter's ServiceMonitor.

The `__address__` relabel is important, thanks to [How to configure prometheus kubernetes_sd_configs to specify a specific host port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603310/how-to-configure-prometheus-kubernetes-sd-configs-to-specify-a-specific-host-por)

Comment: Very good and insightful answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can also use this label from endpoint sd. So, this is probably the most clean way to do this.

```yaml
prometheus-node-exporter:
  prometheus:
    monitor:
      enabled: true
      relabelings:
        - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_node_name]
          targetLabel: node
```

These values are for [kube-prometheus-stack helm chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack). Please update accordingly for your installation.