# How to configure prometheus kubernetes_sd_configs to specify a specific host port?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am running node exporter on GKE on a different port (11100) and configuring prometheus.yml to use kubernetes_sd_configs. However, the service discovery seems to be returning the node IP with *Kubelet* port (10250) `<node-ip>:10250/metrics`. I can’t seem to find a way to specify which port to use. Any ideas?

```yaml
 - job_name: gke-nodes
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
```

Also, node-exporter is running correctly in the port `11100`. I validated it by executing curl in the internal node IP `<node-ip>:11100/metrics` and it works like a charm

---

Here is my Node exporter definition

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: node-exporter-ds
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: node-exporter
    belongsTo: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-exporter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-exporter
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: monitoring-sa
      volumes:
        - name: proc
          hostPath:
            path: /proc
        - name: sys
          hostPath:
            path: /sys
      containers:
        - name: node-exporter
          image: prom/node-exporter:v0.18.1
          args:
            - "--web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:11100"
            - "--path.procfs=/proc_host"
            - "--path.sysfs=/host_sys"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 11100
              hostPort: 11100
          volumeMounts:
          - name: sys
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /host_sys
          - name: proc
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /proc_host
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
```

Comment: How did you setup the prometheus/node exporter?

Comment: I am going to update it in the question so I can show you my node exporter definition

Comment: Could you please share the error messages and logs from prometheus/node exporter?

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone is facing the same issue, this configuration will add the k8s nodes IPs with a different port than *Kubelet*:

```
  - job_name: 'gke-nodes'
    kubernetes_sd_configs: 
    - role: node
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+):.*
        replacement: $1:11100 # port you want to use
        target_label: __address__
```

The default behavior of the *kubernetes_sd_config* is to add as targets the IPs of the nodes with the port of *Kubelet*, this is specified in the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#node):

> The node role discovers one target per cluster node with the address **defaulting** to the **Kubelet's HTTP port**

However, you can use `relabel_config` to override the `__address__` label and replace the *Kubelet* port with any port that need.